# Why should the index of element in vector be exactly int?

Tags: vector, indexing, vhdl

Every time when i want to receive an element from vector (let's say, `std_logic` from `std_logic_vector` via `std_logic_vector(index))`, the index should be exactly an integer (i am using VHDL98 standard).

Could you explain please, why should the index be an integer (and not an unsigned, for example)?
I've googled all over the Internet, but no explanation was found :(

Thank you!

Comment: IEEE Library `std_logic_1164` Package  defines `std_logic_vector` as  ```type STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is array (NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;```

Comment: It doesn't have to be an Integer. But it has to be a discrete type not an array, and Unsigned is an array.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2 Scalar types 5.2.1 General "Enumeration types and integer types are called *discrete* types." 5.3.2 Array types 5.3.2.1 General "The name for an element of an array uses one or more index values belonging to specified discrete types." A value of an unsigned can't be discretely mapped to a binary representation The value of an object of an array type is the value of it's elements. Enumeration types use positional representation.

Comment: This question isn't [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).